# Contract factory deploys a contract - how to interact the contract from the factory

Tags: solidity, truffle, contract-invocation

say I have a contract that is a factory, using truffle in order to interact with it I go for:

```
ContractName.deployed().then(function(instance) {app = instance;})
```

now, the factory has got a function that deploys new contracts which i simply invoke by:

```
app.functionNameForCreatingNewContract({from: web3.accounts[1]})
```

and the above creates a new contract.

Now the 'big question' is how to create an instance of that newly created contract so I could interact with it?

Answer (score 5):

You can use `CONTRACT_NAME.at()` in the console passing in the address of the newly created contract. Example:

Contract code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.19;

contract ParentContract {
  ChildContract _contract;

  function createChildContract(address owner) public {
    _contract = new ChildContract(owner);
  }

  function getContractAddress() public constant returns (address) {
    return address(_contract);
  }
}

contract ChildContract {
  address _owner;

  function ChildContract(address owner) public {
    _owner = owner;
  }

  function getOwner() public constant returns (address) {
    return _owner;
  }
}
```

2_deploy_contracts.js:

```
var ParentContract = artifacts.require("ParentContract");

module.exports = function(deployer) {
  deployer.deploy(ParentContract);
};
```

Deploy with `truffle migrate`:

```
Running migration: 1_initial_migration.js
  Replacing Migrations...
  ... 0x83fa4790e458809dab270f37b5445eaf163e9084a3223b7f6f58fc8237f4a67a
  Migrations: 0x9962b2e8d276b8eacb07fd454ffe4267fb232e0b
Saving successful migration to network...
  ... 0x0cdc86c786c7825226948d93bcfef05f059a7e456a04516a2aedbd1fb7979d41
Saving artifacts...
Running migration: 2_deploy_contracts.js
  Replacing ParentContract...
  ... 0x2f85718df4ee286394a78274afda5d8104bcec19c990d1d3f608a08b2b35fa34
  ParentContract: 0x651cbb04e31699eb92740018e5a8e65f91164903
Saving successful migration to network...
  ... 0x04701683665a47720aa8f60efaca57f123ce85c2228775aec232c834124618ae
Saving artifacts...
```

In `truffle console` (some output truncated):

```
$ truffle console
truffle(development)> var c = ParentContract.at('0x651cbb04e31699eb92740018e5a8e65f91164903');
undefined
truffle(development)> var a;
undefined
truffle(development)> web3.eth.getAccounts((e, r) => a = r[0]);
undefined
truffle(development)> c.createChildContract(a);
{ tx: '0x9f4967618355bb2bf6fe7a110a9be91b594c156f11b09176226966009c170f08',
  receipt:
   { transactionHash: '0x9f4967618355bb2bf6fe7a110a9be91b594c156f11b09176226966009c170f08',
     transactionIndex: 0,
     blockHash: '0xba056ea5b6048dc13099ffd7f3049a2f7ff5378e0c9a5d914e059314ab385634',
     blockNumber: 12,
     gasUsed: 142754,
     cumulativeGasUsed: 142754,
     contractAddress: null,
     logs: [] },
  logs: [] }
truffle(development)> c.getContractAddress();
'0x64b999e71f5fab8b1c5dc718152d84b620cbbef9'
truffle(development)> var c2 = ChildContract.at(c.getContractAddress());
undefined
truffle(development)> c2.getOwner();
'0x9a6d82ef3912d5ab60473124bccd2f2a640769d7'
```

Comment: My reputation is too low  for a vote to be visible, but I did vote on the answer you provided.